# XNA: How do I change a variable value from another class?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm making a Shoot'Em Up game in XNA. I'm making a level system, where every minute, the level will raise and the speed of the enemies will increase.

In my main class (Game1.cs) I have the method that increase the level, and in the `Enemy` Class I have a variable `public int speed = 2;` that is used in the update of the Enemy

```
public override void Update()
{
    base.pos.Y += speed;
}
```

In the `Game1` class, I have this method

```
public void LevelSystemUpdate()
{            
    if (timer > 60f)
    {
        level += 1;
        timer = 0f;
    }
}
```

I want to add a line there like `Enemy.speed += 2;` but it won't let me.

Also, I have this in the `Enemy` class

```
public int Speed
{
    get
    {
        return speed;
    }
    set
    {
        speed = value;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to make it work. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Enemy.Speed += 2` not `Enemy.speed` and make the variable private in `Enemy` class.

Comment: I tried to do that but I get an error: "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property etc.
But I don't want to set Speed += 2 to just an object in the list, I want to change it for the whole class

Comment: Then make it static `public static int speed;`

Comment: I feel like the speed of your ennemies should be calculated upon a difficulty level held somewhere else in your program (difficulty management class). For the difficulty to be managed at only one place, I suggest you use the Singleton pattern either by implementing it yourself or through IoC. Making the speed static is, to my view, a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not doing anything special in the getter & setter of the `Speed` property, you should switch the syntax to the `Auto-Property` as follow:

```
public int Speed { get; set; }
```

This way, you won't need the private field `speed` and therefore won't get mixed up between the 2.

To avoid such mistakes in the future, you could use a naming pattern for your private variables (ex.: m_speed, where "m" is for member).